# Clean webpack plugin clears fonts and images when saving sass file and they aren't rebuilt

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am having an issue with the clean webpack plugin.  It works fine when I first start up but when I save a file like `.scss` it clears everything in the folder which is to be expected.  But webpack never rebuilds the files in my images and fonts folders so the folders are now empty.  I can't find any documentation on why this is happening or how I should handle this [Cleaning up the /dist folder](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/#cleaning-up-the-dist-folder).  Here is my webpack common config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.join(root, 'src/js', 'app'),
  },

  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    path: path.join(root, 'assets'),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
        exclude: [/img/],
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            publicPath: '../fonts',
            outputPath: 'fonts',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jp(e*)g|gif)$/,
        exclude: [/fonts/],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              publicPath: '../img',
              outputPath: 'img',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/app.css',
    }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      proxy: 'http://localhost/wordpress/',
      files: ['**/*.php'],
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: 'src/img', to: 'img' }],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Any help here would be appreciated as there is not much documentation on the clean-webpack-plugin.